# How do I choose one covariate out of many covariates that might have similar effects?

Tags: predictor

I plan to run a logistic regression model to understand the influence of temperature on the occupancy of a hare species. However I can't decide on which aspect of temperature should I consider as my covariate? Is it minimum temperature that I should take? maximum? mean? how do I determine which one would be the best one for my analysis?

Comment: there is no secret method: you try the different ones and report how the conclusions change as your covariates do.

Comment: Thank you very much!